How to deal with routing of distributed signals
How to connect some signals that have many branches, such as SPI & I2C, such as clock? Does it have any special principles and methods? I have read some things, but my information is incomplete.

The problem you probably want to understand is foremost bus capacitance; but you won't get far with this without understanding termination and signal reflections, too. So, that's what people learn in a lecture often called "basics of transmission line theory". It was in my third semester of studying electrical engineering, so you'll need a bit of math basics, but not too many.
In essence:

something has to drive the bus. All the branches form a capacitive load, and that means you need a lot of current capacity in the bus driver to still effect a voltage signal. That might mean the bus architecture you want simply isn't possible at the speeds you want.
signals travel in the electric field between conductors (and not primarily in the conductor); this is a result from basic physics. That also means that the speed of an electric signal isn't infinite, and that reflections will happen at points where the properties of the trace changes, for example at branches and at ends. You get reflections if you don't incorporate that – and these reflections can "live" for much longer than a single symbol duration is. You need to understand how these work, how you can mitigate them, at which speeds and distances they become a problem, and how to re-architect your bus if necessary. That's not going to be possible by rules of thumbs alone; you need to understand transmission line theory, if you're to build things such as large buses or clock trees.

